# How to get dynamic prop from clicked element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React "tree" menu component which has main links with submenus which are dynamically generated by a JSON get call. In the React Inspector I can see that each element on the tree has several props but when I click on each element the only one I can access is value. Here is the props list:

```
{
  "checked": 0,
  "className": null,      
  "label": "192.168.1.71",       
  "isLeaf": false,
  "isParent": true,      
  "title": null,
  "treeId": "rct-~xDYGzs",
  "value": "5bd350bf-8515-4dc2-9b12-16b221505593",            
}
```

Here is the code for accessing the value (which was provided in the component API):

```
onClick(clicked) {
    this.setState({ clicked });
    console.log('You clicked on ' + clicked.value);
}
```

If I substitute any other prop name (like "treeId") for clicked.value I get "undefined". I've tried every variation of e.target and getAttributes but nothing is working. Hopefully this is enough info to get some advice but I can definitely add more if needed. Thanks in advance.

Addendum: This is all being scripted into a pre-existing component called react-checkbox-tree so putting together a Codesandbox would be kind of difficult. I did a console.log(clicked) as suggested and got the following:

```
{value: "5bd81d67-3fd5-464a-b115-161ce291c2d8", checked: false}
```

For whatever reason the remaining props besides value and checked are not reporting and I can't access them and I have tried everything imaginable.

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState({ clicked })` is shorthand for `this.setState({ clicked: clicked })`. This is called [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). If you change that to anything else, then it will rewrite it to (In the case of treeId): `treeId: treeId` (The variable being passed in to the `onClick` function is named `clicked`, so `treeId` will be undefined.)

If you want to set `treeId` to `clicked.value`, simply use:

```
this.setState({
    treeId: clicked.value
});
```

You can still use the object destructing in the parameter, if `value` is on the `clicked` object, and that's all you care about:

```
onClick({ value }) {
    this.setState({ treeId: value });
    console.log(`You clicked on ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: yes pass whole update clicked object in onClick fucntion.

Comment: wow ... thank you so much for your time and attention. Can't wait to try this!

Comment: The problem here is that I don't need the clicked value, I need the treeId, so if I set  the treeId state to clicked.value I am still not getting the treeId, I am getting the value.

Comment: `console.log(clicked)`. Find the value you want inside that object, and use that property instead.

Comment: It only gives me "value" and "checked" props. I think I'm going to have to figure something else out.

Comment: @CHays412 And neither of those values are what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I actually need either "treeId" or "isLeaf" and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access them.

Comment: @CHays412 Post a working reproducible error on codesandbox, and we can assist further.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can only get the [value] prop from your onClick is because other data doesn't get passed along in a mouse event. If you want to return all of the props from your subcomponent you can adjust the way you're writing your click handler to return a function like this:

```
class MainComponent extends Component {
  handleClick(props) {
    console.log(props); /* whatever you sent from the sub component */
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SubComponent
          subComponentClicked={this.handleClick}
      />
    );
  }
}

class SubComponent extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.subComponentClicked(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I will try it ASAP!

Comment: The only props I could get to return with this method were "checked" and "value". I have no idea why the other props aren't reporting.

Comment: That's weird, it should be. Check my codesandbox. It's properly setting the state from the testProp attribute I'm sending: https://codesandbox.io/s/yjm36vn571